# how to check higher number in pairwise matrix in python from dictionary

Tags: python, matrix

I have a dictionary whose keys are strings and values are integers, e.g.:

`name = {'a': 10, 'b': 50, 'c': 20, 'd': 30}`

and I have code for building pairwise matrix. For example:

```
print("\t".join(['']+[a[0] for a in name]))
for a in name:
   print("\t".join([a[0]] + [(str(a[0]+b[0]) if a[0]<b[0] else '') for b in name]))
```

Output:

```
     a     b     c     d
a          ab    ac    ad
b                bc    bd
c                      cd
d
```

How to check string from higher number integer in matrix comparison. For example:

```
     a     b     c     d
a          b     c     d
b                b     b
c                      d
d
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code this can be written as:

```
name = {'a': 10, 'b': 50, 'c': 20, 'd': 30}

print("\t".join(['']+[a[0] for a in name]))
for a in name:
   print("\t".join([a[0]] + [(max(a[0], b[0], key=name.get) if a[0]<b[0] else '') for b in name]))
```